# Integrate graphviz into pandoc

Tags: graphviz, pandoc, dot

I am trying to integrate graphviz using the dot command into pandoc markdown, and I am wondering what the easiest way is to do this. Currently I am creating separate `.dot` files, create images from them using the `dot` command manually on the command line into a separate file, and finally  add that file using the image syntax of markdown:

```
![](./path/to/image.png)
```

But since the dot syntax is similar easy to read than markdown, I would prefer to have dot integrated in markdown. It feels like this should be possible, because in the [pandoc filters page](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) this is given as an example. It is just that I don't want to code that on my own, but would like to use some package that is ready to use. Does something like that exist?

Comment: https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/diagram-generator#graphviz

Comment: Happy you found it helpful :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tarleb posted a link to https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/diagram-generator#graphviz in the comments, which was a great help. Using a lua-filter is really. Adapted the linked script a bit to match my needs.

The script now looks like the following:

```lua
-- insprired from https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/5686d96/diagram-generator/diagram-generator.lua

local dotPath = os.getenv("DOT") or "dot"

local filetype = "svg"
local mimetype = "image/svg+xml"

local function graphviz(code, filetype)
    return pandoc.pipe(dotPath, {"-T" .. filetype}, code)
end

function CodeBlock(block)
    local converters = {
        graphviz = graphviz,
    }

    local img_converter = converters[block.classes[1]]
    if not img_converter then
      return nil
    end

    local success, img = pcall(img_converter, block.text, filetype)

    if not success then
        io.stderr:write(tostring(img))
        io.stderr:write('\n')
        error 'Image conversion failed. Aborting.'
    end

    return pandoc.RawBlock('html', img)
end

return {
    {CodeBlock = CodeBlock},
}
```

The pandoc option `--lua-filter` can then be used to add this filter to the conversion:

```sh
pandoc\
    slides.md\
    -o slides.html\
    --lua-filter=codeblock-filter.lua
```

Also added more explanation in [my blog](https://danrot.github.io/2020/03/28/creating-highly-customizable-html-presentation-with-markdown-and-pandoc.html).